# Projection of a point onto the intersection of the hyperplane and the hypercube

Tags: geometry

Let $\Delta$ be the $n$-dimensional hypercube with side 1,
$$
\Delta=\{x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n: \quad 0\leq x_k \leq 1 \quad \forall k=\overline{1,n}\},
$$
and $\Gamma$ be the hyperplane,
$$
\Gamma=\{x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n: \quad x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n=\gamma\}
$$
where $0<\gamma<n$.

I have to find the projection of a point $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ onto the intersection $\Gamma\cap\Delta$.

I know that the projection of a point $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ onto the hyperplane $\Gamma$ is the point $u=(u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_n),$
$$
u_k=x_k-\frac{1}{n}\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_j-\gamma\bigg), \quad k=\overline{1,n},
$$
and the projection of a point $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ onto the hypercube $\Delta$ is the point $v=(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n),$
$$
v_k=\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
0 \quad \text{if} \quad x_k<0, \\
1 \quad \text{if} \quad x_k>1, \\
x_k \quad \text{if} \quad 0\leq x_k\leq 1.
\end{array}\right.
$$
But how to find the formula for the projection onto the intersection $\Gamma\cap\Delta?$